# CPython - access loop depth level - block stack

Tags: python, stack, cpython, inspect

I'm trying to write a nice logging Formatter, which would add a tabulation depending on the depth level in loop / function calls.

I can access the stack depth with `len(inspect.stack())`, but that gives me only the number of frames, not accounting for the loops.

I believe that you can retrieve the depth of the loop from the CPython block stack, but I haven't found any way to access it **at runtime** (maybe `dis`?).

**Example**

```py
def run():
    logger.info("Starting program")
    # Some stuff
    f()
    
def f():
    logger.info("In f")
    for i in range(3):
         # Code here
         logger.info("From within loop! "+str(i))

logger.info("From main module")
run()
logger.info("Done")
```

desired output

```py
From main module
    Starting program
        In f
            From within loop! 0
            From within loop! 1
            From within loop! 2
Done
```

**Note**: I'd rather not change a bit of my code (no keeping track of the depth manually incremented).

Comment: Python has no concept of "loop depth", you could probably figure out if you are *inside* a for-loop, but not what iteration it's at

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, the [block stack](https://leanpub.com/insidethepythonvirtualmachine/read#leanpub-auto-the-block-stack) contains one block per loop, and could therefore be used to determine the depth.